# How to get file structure array from fs in next.js

Tags: node.js, next.js, filesystems

#### What I want is

Currently, I'm creating a blog with Next and React and want to show the structure of the file on the frontend side.
Using fs, I already made variables for this array of files thanks to answers from StackOverflow.
Usually, I use the file variable in `getPosts` function in the `getStaticPaths`

```js
export const getAllSubFolders = (
  baseFolder: string,
  folderList: string[] = [],
) => {
  const folders: string[] = fs
    .readdirSync(baseFolder)
    .filter((file) => fs.statSync(path.join(baseFolder, file)).isDirectory());

  folders.forEach((folder) => {
    folderList.push(path.join(baseFolder, folder));
    getAllSubFolders(path.join(baseFolder, folder), folderList);
  });
  return folderList;
};

export const getFilesInFolder = (rootPath: string) => fs
  .readdirSync(rootPath)
  .filter(
    (filePath) => !fs.statSync(path.join(rootPath, filePath)).isDirectory(),
  )
  .map((filePath) => path.normalize(path.join(rootPath, filePath)));

export const getFilesRecursively = (rootPath: string) => getAllSubFolders(rootPath)
  . reduce((result, folder) => [...result, ...getFilesInFolder(folder)], [] as string[]);


export const files = getFilesRecursively('pages')

console.log(files)

  // [
  //   'pages/posts/backend/aaa.mdx',
  //   'pages/posts/frontend/bbb.mdx',
  //   'pages/posts/retrospective/bbbccc.mdx',
  //   'pages/posts/retrospective/dddd.mdx',
  // ]
```

#### The problem is

When I call the files array in frontend component, the error message says,
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'` even I import fs in the file that includes `getFilesRecursively` function.

How can I call the `files` array in the frontend side?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that on the frontend side, cannot handle fs so I made JSON file using fs.